# What should be the keep aspect ratio parameter in faster rcnn tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am creating a model for ice bubble detection using `Tensorflow`. Here, I need to edit `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config)

All of my train and test images have size of 400 by 400 pixel except 3 images have 220 by 400 pixel, whereas bubble objects are of different size (i.e. 10 by 10 or 8 by 10)

For this cases, I am confused about what should be the parameter from below in `min_dimension` and `max_dimension` instead of 600 and 1000 to get expected detection?

```
image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep_aspect_ratio_resizer function resizes the images if any of the two dimensions of those images are out of this `min_dimension` and `max_dimension` ranges and it will keep the same aspect ratio what the input image had.

If any input image has a dimension, let's say 400 pixel and the other dimension let's say 600, this function will resize the dimensions so that the image's smaller dimension is 600 (according to your mentioned code) and accordingly the larger dimension will be such a value so that the aspect ratio (400/600) of input image is maintained.

You can find a nice discussion regarding this [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1794)